# How to be calm, professional and attentive when going for software development interviews, yet not seem too excited and give wrong signals?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, tech-industry

**Please note that this is related to the tech industry specifically and not necessarily a generic question.** TL;DR: I tried searching but could not find an answer as this relates specifically to the interview process. How to go "dating" with companies (I am the one attending interviews) and remain professional but even-keeled?

As a developer we have people asking for interviews very quickly after applying. Sometimes this is a red flag, sometimes it's just the nature of talent shortage in the industry.

Certainly I should be thankful. In any case, my main question is how to conduct myself during the interview process. Mainly stopping myself from rushing into the first or first few interviews and offers.

I understand in the offer consideration phase there are answers. Again, I need advice on the **interview** stages, as relates to the tech industry and software development positions.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear: are you attending an interview as an applicant for a new job (interviewee) or as representative of company hiring new people (interviewer)?

Comment: ... are you essentially just asking "how should I job search"? I get the impression you're not sure how interviews are supposed to work but I'm not sure where to begin addressing that. Can you [edit] your question to focus on a more practical question or rephrase the issue you're facing?

Comment: Why do you want to appear non-committal? If you don't seem excited, that will just make them less excited about you. Your problem seems to be more about finding the right questions to ask and things to listen for to properly evaluate a company and job, because that's where you should be looking for red flags. If everyone's happy, there's really no reason to drag out the interview process. (Of course too much excitement makes you appear *desperate*, which is bad, but this doesn't appear to be your question)

Comment: @Dukeling when I say non-committal means I don't want to show too much excitement or too much enthusiasm because that either shows desperation or may make the employer very disappointed if I don't take the job. By non-committal I also mean not getting myself hyped up too much that this first or second job is so awesome and I forget about evaluating other job options.

Comment: @Lilienthal and YElm I mean I am attending interviews, how to approach it in a calm and rational manner. Again, I am specifically talking about tech industry software development positions. No offense to anyone (not you per se) but please don't give a generic answer as far as possible.

Comment: @YElm No worries, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interviewing goes both ways.

They're interviewing you to see if you're suitable for the job being offered, and you're answering those questions to prove your suitability for the role.

Part of your job as an interviewee is to judge whether you want to work for this company or not.  You should be asking questions toward this end. What are their working practices?  How do they manage projects?  How do they manage projects failing to meet their objectives?  What benefits do they offer?

These questions should help prevent you from rushing to accept the first jobs that are offered to you (unless the answers are good ones, of course).

Comment: Thanks, accepting this answer as the best and most relevant to the challenges I shall face in the next several weeks. "How do they manage projects failing to meet their objectives?" --> This is very salient and something interviewees should note (certainly in software development in my case).

Answer (score 3):

As an interviewer, I ***strongly prefer*** candidates who are obviously interested in software development. Surely, that should be obvious? Why on earth would you want to not show interest, enthusiasm, even passion?

When being interviewed, I generally find it difficult to conceal my passion, especially of the interviewer is equally passionate. That helps us to connect, improves my chances of landing the job, and would probably help with nerves, I imagine (I don't suffer).

Comment: I think I go too far and show too much passion and enthusiasm. In Asian countries this can be a drawback. Not so much in Western countries where I've been. As for the interviewer, again, this might be a situation in Asian countries, but the hiring process can be weeding out people that are underskilled, fake or the company trying to get the cheapest worker possible. Yesterday despite showing online a potential employer a working site with registration and login, he wanted to see closed-source, proprietary source code and be able to login to the back-end admin system of my previous company.

Comment: Although I am western, I have worked in Hong Kong, China, Japan & Singapore for a dozen years or more. As an interviewer there, I still looked for passion, but I am also aware of "the company trying to get the cheapest worker possible". E.g, Singaporean companies often prefer mainland Chinese to Singaporeans. I doubt that passion would hurt, though, just show them that they will get more bang for their SGD. I can't say about being interviewed. I worked either for MNCs or local customers of MNCs who accepted me on the MNC's recommendation.

Comment: Cheers, I am referring to Malaysia where the situation is more, uh, sedentary compared to Singapore (the two countries were somewhat similar but became very divergent in the past few decades). And MNCs are certainly different. To shed more cultural light on the situation, because I've spent quite some time overseas despite being a citizen here, interviewers are put quite off-balance when I speak and present myself (outside of MNCs and/or Western expat interviewers). In any case I appreciate your perspective. Thanks.

Comment: Lolx! I am Sg PR, currently in Europe, and wish that I could go back. I also heartily enjoyed MY.

Comment: Hey being an expat is very, very different to working the scene as a local ;)

Comment: I know. I do live like a local, totally avoiding Western bars & restaurants. I paid $3 for at the food court, lived in an HDB - otherwise, what's the point of living overseas? But nothing I could do would prevent management giving me favourable treatment over locals. Parts of that is my sought-after expertise, but some is just plain ...

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with attending interviews, even if you are not planning to join the company. It's good to practice every now and then. As for jumping to offers - set your bar high. Promise yourself to only accept if the offer is really substantial to you. Maybe 40 % raise? Maybe a very short commute, if your current one is really long? Or something you could see yourself enjoying for minimum 4-5 years. Set that limit before you get the offer.

Comment: Yes, this is helpful to have parameters in mind to be professional but objective.